# CentOS yum don't see some packages in base repository

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I'm trying to run `yum update` on CentOS7. However it produces an error that some dependencies are required. For example:

```
Error: Package: pyldb-1.5.4-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: python-tdb(x86-64) >= 1.3.18
```

The `python-tdb` is in the `CentOS x86_64` repository, but `sudo yum install python-tdb` produces:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.centos.lax1.serverforge.org
 * centos-sclo-rh: repos-lax.psychz.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: centos.mirror.ndchost.com
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirrors.xmission.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * updates: mirrors.xmission.com
No package python-tdb available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

If I try to install some other packages, for example `lynx` from the same repository everything works fine.

Th question - why yum can't find `python-tdb` and some others packages?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you try to download that rpm manually and then install it with `sudo yum install <path to rpm>` or `sudo rpm -Uvh <path to rpm`? The first command should download any dependent packages, while the latter will not.

Comment: Thanks, The first command just said `Error: Nothing to do`, but the second asked to update `libtdb` and after manual update it seems to resolve issue. Still strange - is this is and error with package dependences or something with my yum?

Comment: And the output of `sudo yum list python-tdb` ? 
Also, what happens if you previously remove the package causing the error?